# Animated Gifs Flicker on Android 2.2+

Tags: android, gif, animated-gif

I've got an interesting situation with Android 2.2+ when multiple animated gifs are on-screen they flicker and flash white.  On certain devices, multiple Gifs will not animate past the first frame or so.

I've got an Android tablet hooked up to Chrome via the ADB, and haven't discovered any useful logging data.

Any thoughts on displaying multiple animated gifs on screen with Android?  My initial reaction was a memory issue, however running an Android simulator with 4GB of ram and 512MB video ram doesn't seem to help.

Comment: How are you displaying these? IIRC, Android did not support animate GIFs back then at all, let alone several at once.

Comment: They're being displayed as background-image in floating divs.  Background fit to 'cover'.

Answer (score 0):

A well known trick of boosting performance (at the cost of mobile battery life) is to initiate a neutral 3D transform on certain elements within the DOM.

Here's the code that initiates the "overdrive" mode of most modern browsers:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
-moz-transform: translateZ(0);
-ms-transform: translateZ(0);
-o-transform: translateZ(0);
transform: translateZ(0);
```

As it turns out, Android has a hard time rendering Gifs in this enhanced rendering mode.  Possibly because the DOM is being redrawn over and over so frequently.

Cheers!